# what does this error mean in Paypal developer "braintreeCredentials.validCountryLiveTokenError"?"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

what does this error mean in Paypal developer "**braintreeCredentials.validCountryLiveTokenError**"?
I live in Portugal.

Thanks

Comment: Which API you are calling in Braintree?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include more informations about what you are actually trying to do, and include some code. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for help me.

Comment: I'm new in paypal develeoper. On test sandbox Account, there are no Portugal country in test (euro), but perhaps with real live payment this is possible. I'm using wordpress with "Sell Media" plugin, Test with country Spain (euro) works. Thanks for your help.